# How can I copy a folder to a new folder renamed with the sysdate?

Tags: vbscript

How can I copy a folder (with all subfolders) to a new folder on a remote server and rename the new folder with the sysdate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't bother with VBScript. Use `robocopy` instead:

```
robocopy C:\some\folder \\server\C$\somewhere\%DATE% /e
```

Depending on your system's regional settings (e.g. if your date format uses `/` as delimiter) you may need to modify the value of the system variable `%DATE%`:

```
robocopy C:\some\folder \\server\C$\somewhere\%DATE:/=-% /e
```